# LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined

Tags: errors

Please Help me to get rid of the following error:

```
    ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mytheorem\demonstration.sty"
Package: demonstration 


! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   \vrule\hfil}}
```

Giving by this code source:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \usepackage[calcwidth,raggedright,bf,sf]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{slashbox}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{turnstile}
    \usepackage{bbding}
    \usepackage{shadethm}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
    \geometry{left=-1cm, right=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm}  
    \setlength{\shadeboxrule}{.4pt}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \def\mathbi#1{\textbf{\em #1}}
    \newlength{\shadowbaseline}
    \newcommand{\shadowbaselinebox}[1]{%
      \leavevmode
      \setlength{\shadowbaseline}
                        {\fboxsep+\fboxrule+\heightof{#1}}%
      \hbox{\vbox to \shadowbaseline{%
                  \hbox{\protect\shadowbox{#1}}}}%
    }
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}
    \setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
    \setlength{\headsep}{0.7cm}
    \setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
    \setlength{\textheight}{25cm}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}
    \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\textbf{\alph{enumii}}}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumii.}}
    \everymath{\displaystyle\everymath{}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
       \markboth{%
         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
           \if@mainmatter
             \@chapapp\nobreakspace
             \shadowbaselinebox{\thechapter}\nobreakspace
           \fi
         \fi
       #1}{}}
    \makeatother
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{ \scshape \leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\scshape  \nouppercase \rightmark }
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{ \scshape  \textsc{ My institut}} 
    \fancyfoot[LO]{ \scshape \textsc{Title} }
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\shadowbaselinebox{\thepage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{one}
    \limpsum
    \chapter{Two}
    \lipsum
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Without a MWE is vey difficult to answer and it's not easy to find demonstration.sty. Surprise ! there are 121 packages inside the mytheorem's folder. The problem is simple : demonstration.sty uses `\newcommand{\openbox}` and `openbox` is already defined but where ?

Comment: As Altermundus pointed out, there is actually nothing wrong with the `\vrule\hfil`, it's just the code which follows on line 13 in that file. The real error message is `! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.` of course. You should change the title of your question accordantly.

Comment: Your example shows a lot of typical problems: Your preamble includes a bunch of packages you probably don't need (you forgot the kitchen sink), you have code you most likely don't need (redefining `\chaptermark`), and code that should be left to packages (you include `geometry` _and_ set the page dimens directly). Start again with a _minimal_ document.

Comment: I do not seem to have the `slashbox` package, and is `\limpsum` intended to be `\lipsum`?  Once I remove the `slashbox` package, add the `calc` package, and correct `\limpsum`, your example compiles for me. Please provide a [MWE]((http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) that actually illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 14):

try

```
\let\openbox\relax
\usepackage{demonstration}
```

Comment: wow ! worked liked a charm.

Answer (score 13):

The code tries to define the command `\openbox`, which is already defined. This leads to that error message. Check your file `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mytheorem\demonstration.sty` for this.

Very probably you already loaded a package, which defines `\openbox`. For example, `amsthm` and `ntheorem` both define it, and both in the same way:

```
\newcommand{\openbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.77778em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.675em{\hrule width.6em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
```

You can see the commands

```
\vrule\hfil}}
```

from your error message.

Remove the package(s) from your preamble, which you don't need. And if you need it and you would like to keep it, don't define the same command again or use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` if it's your intention to change a macro definition.